# How to pass 2 string variables in exec_command

Tags: python

```
import paramiko
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('hostname', username='test1234', password='test')
path = ['/home/test/', '/home/test1/','/home/test3/']
sftp = client.open_sftp()
check = 'tail -f /home/test/logs/check.out'
for filename in sftp.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        h = path + filename 
        stdin,stdout,stderr = client.exec_command('%s && %s | grep -i "Connection time out"' %path %check)
        stdout = = revout.read().decode().splitlines()
        print stdout
```

i tried to pass 2 string at a time to exec_command. But it's not working.
how to pass 2 string at a time?

Comment: What if you use `str.format`?

Comment: script is not executing prompting to next line. No error as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use

`'%s && %s | grep -i "Connection time out"' % (path,check)`

or Python 3's `.format`

`'{0} && {1} | grep -i "Connection time out"'.format(path,check)`